# Meteor - better way to update an array in a collection , server side

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, collections

I looking for a better way to make this update in the server side, you will notice that :
segmentos.0 ...segmentos.1 ... segmentos.2...segmentos.3 only changed the number. I tried to use a "for" loop  and segmentos.i , but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

```
Partidas.update({_id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName}, {"$set": {"usuarios.$.segmentos.0.eficienciaPicked":0 }, }, );
Partidas.update({_id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName}, {"$set": {"usuarios.$.segmentos.1.eficienciaPicked":0},   }, );
Partidas.update({_id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName}, {"$set": {"usuarios.$.segmentos.2.eficienciaPicked":0},   }, );
Partidas.update({_id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName}, {"$set": {"usuarios.$.segmentos.3.eficienciaPicked":0 },   }, );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Partidas.update(
    {_id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName},
    { $set: 
        { "usuarios.$.segmentos": 
            [ { eficienciaPicked: 0 }, { eficienciaPicked: 0 }, { eficienciaPicked: 0 }, { eficienciaPicked: 0 } ] 
        } 
    } 
);
```

will accomplish the same thing in one update.

If the number of elements in the array is dynamic, build it in a variable using a for loop before the update, and $set it to the var.

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit about that "something" please, I tried with something and it didn't work.        
Partidas.update({_id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName}, {"$set": {"usuarios.$.segmentos"[{eficienciaPicked:0},{eficienciaPicked:0},{eficienciaPicked:0},{eficienciaPicked:0},{eficienciaPicked:0}],}   }, );

Comment: the $ take the first user who answer the consult: _id:id, "usuarios.name" : usuarioName  ,  from an array of "usuarios". 
My DB is like Partidas.usuarios[user].segmentos[segment]. So the $ put my inside of the user I looking for, but this user has "segmentos" with an array of 5 segments, and I want to get inside of this segments

Comment: With that data model it should work as I edited it now?

Comment: I tried it and almost work.
The change do what is promise, the only big problem, is that delete all the rest of values. Because every "segment" has a name, a value,a cost and a eficienciaPicked. After the change, the only tribute is eficienciaPicked

Comment: Well, you know, if you ask questions without giving all the relevant information in the question, you will not get answers that take that information into account. You have created a difficult data-model for yourself. The MongoDB $ operator can only handle one level of nesting, so you cannot use it here, since you have array inside array I can see no better way of doing it than your original implementation, or doing it inside a for loop, which will work well if you do it right. But it won't be atomic, of course.